# CakePHP: Send emails for crashes

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

What's the best way to add email notifications for CakePHP crashes? I want to be emailed with a stacktrace whenever a fatal error occurs, so that I can know immediately instead of checking the logs.

I looked at overriding `AppController::appError();` but I don't want to replace all of the exception handling.

Comment: You've probably already considered this, but could you create `AppController::appError();` with the email code and then just call `parent::appError();`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Comment: @ahjohnston25 I vaguely remember there being another hook that was better for this, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it is to long to paste here.

https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/develop/Error/EmailErrorHandler.php

It is a customized error handler for CakePHP. [You need to configure CakePHP to use that error handler class.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-your-own-error-handler) My pull request to the core was rejected that introduced an Event in the handleError() method... An event there would make it really easy to handle use cases like this.